# C++11 and [17.5.2.1.3] Bitmask Types

Tags: c++, enums, c++11, bitmask, libc++

The Standard allows one to choose between an integer type, an `enum`, and a `std::bitset`.

**Why would a library implementor use one over the other given these choices?**

Case in point, llvm's libcxx appears to use a combination of (at least) two of these implementation options:

`ctype_base::mask` is implemented using an integer type:
[`<__locale>`](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/__locale?revision=151720&view=markup)

`regex_constants::syntax_option_type` is implemented using an `enum` + overloaded operators:
[`<regex>`](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/regex?revision=145624&view=markup)

The gcc project's libstdc++ uses all *three*:

`ios_base::fmtflags` is implemented using an enum + overloaded operators: [`<bits/ios_base.h>`](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2b%2b-v3/include/bits/ios_base.h;h=ace307cba5359b06ff35f3385e23c8505ab2ae22;hb=HEAD)

`regex_constants::syntax_option_type` is implemented using an integer type,
`regex_constants::match_flag_type` is implemented using a `std::bitset`
Both: [`<bits/regex_constants.h>`](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2b%2b-v3/include/bits/regex_constants.h;h=bddef3a26deedca48e8cbe58b731a5151e47ffbd;hb=HEAD)

AFAIK, gdb cannot "detect" the bitfieldness of any of these three choices so there would not be a difference wrt enhanced debugging.

The `enum` solution and integer type solution should always use the same space. `std::bitset` does not seem to make the guarantee that `sizeof(std::bitset<32>) == std::uint32_t` so I don't see what is particularly appealing about `std::bitset`.

The `enum` solution seems slightly less type safe because the combinations of the masks does not generate an enumerator.

Strictly speaking, the aforementioned is with respect to [n3376](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) and not FDIS (as I do not have access to FDIS).

Any available enlightenment in this area would be appreciated.

Comment: n3376: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf

Comment: N3376 is just a revision of the C++11 standard that fixes minor editorial issues. There is no difference in the content.

Comment: I am quite aware, just wanted to be clear. Thanks for the help with those links :)

Comment: I suppose you already know that, but I think it bears repeating: more often than not, enumeration types can hold many more values than just the set of their enumerators, so binary operations can be just fine on them. It's in fact easier to ensure that it works since we can know specify an explicit underlying type.

Comment: Whatever guarantees the Standard makes about any of these alternatives, an implementer can add more integral types, enumeration type features, or additional constraints to `bitset`. But these types aren't an efficiency concern so no effort is likely to be made.

Answer (score 2):

The really surprising thing is that the standard restricts it to just three alternatives. Why shouldn't a class type be acceptable? Anyway…

- Integral types are the simplest alternative, but they lack type safety. Very old legacy code will tend to use these as they are also the oldest.
- Enumeration types are safe but cumbersome, and until C++11 they tended to be fixed to the size and range of `int`.
- `std::bitset` may be have somewhat more type safety in that `bitset<5>` and `bitset<6>` are different types, and addition is disallowed, but otherwise is unsafe much like an integral type. This wouldn't be an issue if they had allowed types *derived* from `std::bitset<N>`.

Clearly `enum`s are the ideal alternative, but experience has proven that the type safety is really unnecessary. So they threw implementers a bone and allowed them to take easier routes. The short answer, then, is that **laziness leads implementers to choose `int` or `bitset`.**

It is a little odd that types derived from `bitset` aren't allowed, but really that's a minor thing.

The main specification that clause provides is the set of operations defined over these types (i.e., the bitwise operators).

Comment: Nowhere in the standard does it say that these types are restricted to **only** these three alternatives. These are just the three that the OP is talking about. As for type-safety being unnecessary, that's most certainly a fact *not* in evidence...

Comment: @NicolBolas The cited paragraph says "Each bitmask type can be im- plemented as an enumerated type that overloads certain operators, as an integer type, or as a bitset (20.5)." That sounds like an exclusive list of only three alternatives.

Comment: @NicolBolas If type safety between different types of flags were important, libraries wouldn't use integral types for them. But OP gave such an example. So yes, the evidence points to little importance being placed on that. You need to cool down a bit.

Comment: _What_ is it that is supposedly restricted to these three types? Do we even know what we are talking about?

Answer (score 2):

My preference is to use an enum, but there are sometimes valid reasons to use an integer. Usually `ctype_base::mask` interacts with the native OS headers, with a mapping from `ctype_base::mask` to the `<ctype.h>` implementation-defined constants such as `_CTYPE_L` and `_CTYPE_U` used for `isupper` and `islower` etc.  Using an integer might make it easier to use ctype_base::mask directly with native OS APIs.

I don't know why libstdc++'s `<regex>` uses a `std::bitset`. When that code was committed I made a mental note to replace the integer types with an enumeration at some point, but `<regex>` is not a priority for me to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Why would the standard allow different ways of implementing the library? And the answer is: Why not?

As you have seen, all three options are obviously used in some implementations. The standard doesn't want to make existing implementations non-conforming, if that can be avoided.

One reason to use a bitset could be that its size fits better than an enum or an integer. Not all systems even have a `std::uint32_t`. Maybe a `bitset<24>` will work better there?

Comment: Another question is why mix-and-match, which does not make much sense to me.

This also does not explain `enum` vs integer type, which libcxx, a new implementation uses. While it is true that `std::uint32_t` does not exist on a platform, `uint_least32_t` is guaranteed to exist on all platforms. I cannot imagine that this is also an plausible reason because none of them go as far as using `: uint_least8_t` on their `enum` based bitmasks.

Comment: In the case of gcc, different parts of the library are written by different people, and at different times. That might make for different choices. I bet `ios_base` was designed at least 10 years before `regex`. And even though `uint_least32_t` exists on all platforms, we don't know its size. It might sometimes be mapped to `unsigned long long` which could be an overkill.

Comment: I agree with the bitset point so far as why it is an implementation option.

This could be reasonable if `std::bitset` were implemented using an array of type `char` but it uses an array of type `long` in libstdc++-v3